# Bad gradle code from LibGdx book?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I am using Learning LibGDX Game Development and I am on trying to follow the Gradle way. In chapter 4 at the bottom of page 144 it says add:

```
compile "com.badlogic.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
```

underneath the section with this code:

```
project(":desktop")
```

The build.gradle that I inherited from the book's website is posted below. I added the code in the section with "-desktop" but I got an error from Eclipse.

Here is my error:

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.badlogic.gdx:gdx-
tools:1.6.4] on org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseProject_Decorated@54d80175.
```

I am brand spanking new to Gradle, does anybody know what I should do if I want to add the gdx-tools.jar via Gradle?

Build.gradle for desktop project:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.packetpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}

dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse {
    project {
        name = appName + "-desktop"
        linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/android/assets'
        compile "com.badlogic.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project generation", group: "IDE") {
  doLast {
    def classpath = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
    new Node(classpath, "classpathentry", [ kind: 'src', path: 'assets' ]);
    def writer = new FileWriter(file(".classpath"))
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
    printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
    printer.print(classpath)
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion", see: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#tools-gradle

Comment: I do not get the error anymore, but when I go to Gradle->Refresh Dependencies, the gdx-tools jar does not appear in my Gradle Dependencies folder. Am I still doing it wrong?

Comment: You have a root build.gradle and different gradle files for each sub-project (desktop, android, ios etc.), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old domain, which is wrong:

compile "com.**badlogic**.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"

Please, replace it for this new:

compile "com.**badlogicgames**.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"

Ensure you put in the correct place:

```
Tools Gradle

Core Dependency: Dont put me in core!
Desktop Dependency:  compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
Android Dependency: Not compatible!
iOS Dependency: Not compatible!
HTML Dependency: Not compatible!
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be under **dependencies** branch. But there is no **gdxVersion** defined in this gradle file also.

I assume you can use a workaround as defining your variable and using under dependencies by adding this code to the end of the gradle file you shared.

```
dependencies {
    def gdxVersion = '1.6.4'
    compile "com.badlogic.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    //you can add another libraries as well
}
```

But I recommend you to manage libGDX dependencies in the project's gradle file for the consistency of module's libGDX versions. By default, libGDX setup creates **build.gradle** file in the **project's root directory**. And **gdxVersion** variable and libGDX dependencies are defined and managed in this file. Like as:

```
//defines common variables and settings that all projects (modules like desktop, ios, android) use
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'YOUR_PROJECT_NAME'
        gdxVersion = '1.7.0'
        roboVMVersion = '1.8.0'
        gwtVersion = '2.6.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

//and here desktop module specific settings
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    }
}
```

With this usage, you can see that all module's libGDX dependencies can be handled by the same way in the desktop module's depencendies. And you can update your libGDX version with one change to the gdxVersion above.